# highcharts - Trying to use csv data source, getting 'e.replace is not a function'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Below is my complete code. I have more or less copied it from the tutorial on the highcharts site. 'data.csv' file is located in the same folder as my HTML file (I also tried entering the full file path). Using breakpoints, I confirmed that the data from the file is being loaded, no problems. It is at some step I can't pinpoint that I keep getting the error 'e.replace is not a function'. The best I can tell is this is from a file called data.js. The only instance of 'e.replace' is this:

```
parseCSV: function () {
            var b = this,
            a = this.options,
            e = a.csv,
            f = this.columns,
            d = a.startRow || 0,
            c = a.endRow || Number.MAX_VALUE,
            h = a.startColumn || 0,
            q = a.endColumn || Number.MAX_VALUE,
            i,
            g,
            s = 0;
            e && (g = e.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').replace(/\r/g, '\n').split(a.lineDelimiter || '\n'), i = a.itemDelimiter || (e.indexOf('\t') !== - 1 ? '\t' : ','), j(g, function (a, e) { //SNIP
```

But if I keep a breakpoint at that line, the execution never seems to go there...

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    // Get the CSV and create the chart
    $.get('data.csv', function (csv) {

        $('#container').highcharts({

            data: {
                csv: csv
            },

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Data Source Test'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },

            yAxis: { // right y axis
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            }


        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.css" />

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am sorry if this question sounds stupid but I have been at this for 2 days, and have tried all possible internet searches without luck.

Update: I was finally able to see where exactly the error occurred, and I can confirm that it is in the piece of code pasted on top. When it reached the line in question, the value of 'e' is shown as 'Document' with location 'null'. There is a lot of other information but I am not sure which of it will be useful. Let me know if anything in particular is required and I will post it.

Comment: can you post an example of data from the csv file?

Comment: These are the entire contents of the CSV file:

Categories,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15

--(Inexperienced on StackOverflow. Can I not add line breaks in comments?)

Comment: Shift + enter to break row

Comment: Tried that... It shows a breakline while typing, but they are removed after posting. 
--line 1 <br>
--line 2

Comment: For debugging use http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js - that way you will get variable names instead of a,b,c,... I am unable to recreate your issue - http://jsfiddle.net/yf25vL3b/ 

Are you sure that your data is as you say it is? Maybe you will be able to recreate your problem in a JSFiddle? You can load CSV from HTML for the purpose of the example like here - [HC demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/csv/)

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to use the data.src.js file for debugging. When I look at the scripts in firebug I only see data.js, which has a, b, etc. Could this be an issue because the data.csv file is on my local machine?

Comment: Okay, I figured out that I just had to replace the call for data.js with data.src.js. The only difference seems to be that 'e.replace' has been replaced with 'csv.replace'. I also found this additional comment: XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: file:///C:/Users/~/HighCharts/examples/line-ajax/data.csv Line Number 1, Column 1: Categories,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums ^